# Magento Controller shows all the rows from table

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

As I am required to pirnt the ratings of products in JSON format, i have made a module with controller and rating.php file in model folder. We I run the controller it shows all the data from that table, But I required only a single row. So through the url i am passing a parameter, but it wont works. I am attaching my indexcontroller.php here. suggest me upon this.

```
<?php 
class Modulename_CustomRating_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

  public function indexAction ()
   { 

$arrParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

  var_dump($arrParams);

$collection = Mage::getModel('Modulename_CustomRating_Model_CustomRating')->getCollection();
}
print_r (json_encode($collection ->getData()));



 }

}

?>
```

As I am passing url as:localhost/magento/customrating?vote_id=1 , it is taking the parameter to it but  returns whole table's data. I know this is due to getData(); but how to make to get the required row?

Comment: You should look at the addAttributeToFilter() function and add something like ->addAttributeToFilter('vote_id',$arrParams['vote_id']) to your collection.

Comment: I didn't understand. Did you want multiple rows (all products) with only two columns (product id, rating) or one row (filtered by product id) with the whole data for that product?

Comment: @enenen I want only one row filtered by product Id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `setEntityPkFilter` method. Check `Mage_Rating_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection` class for other methods.

```
$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id'); // or 'vote_id'

$collection = Mage::getModel('Modulename_CustomRating_Model_CustomRating')
              ->getResourceCollection()
              ->setEntityPkFilter($product_id);
```

---

If you want only 1 column you can try some Zend stuff because you can't use `addAttributeToSelect`. `getSelect()` returns Zend like query:

```
$adapter = $this->getConnection(); // $this->getConnection();

$collection->getSelect()
           ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS) // remove all columns
           ->columns('attribute_name'); // add only needed one

$result = $adapter->fetchAll($select);
```

Not sure whether this would work. It's not tested, just an idea.

Comment: it returns a fatal error as call to undefined method..Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Rating_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection::addAttributeToSelect() in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Modulename/CustomRating/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13 Call Stack: 0.0001 324872 1. {main}() /var/www/html/magento/index.php:0 0.0023 413312

Comment: Try with `setEntityPkFilter`. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yes sir.. It works.Thank you. But it returns all the columns of data. How can I restrict here the other columns like if I want only percent column as if we give pk value?

Comment: Usually it's done with `addAttributeToSelect` but you don't have access to it from this model. You can try with Zend's methods. Will edit my answer again.

Comment: After `getSelect()` you already haven't collection but typical ZF query. So you have to fetch the result with `fetchAll`, not with `getData`.